# Different values on each hashing approach

Tags: c++, hash

can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong? i'm trying to hash a value with murmurhash, but i get different values every time:

```
std::string str = "some test string";
char out[32];

MurmurHash3_x86_32(str.c_str(), str.length(), 0, out);
unsigned int hash = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(out);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like `MurmurHash3_x86_32` is returning a 32 bits hash value. But you're giving it a 32 **bytes** output parameter.

You could simply:

```
std::string str = "some test string";

unsigned int hash;
MurmurHash3_x86_32(str.c_str(), str.length(), 0, &hash);
```

Answer (score 9):

The variable `out` is of type `char []`, or array of `char`. This acts as a pointer to `char` in most contexts. Here, you're casting the pointer value, not the pointed-to contents.

Also, I don't know the MurmurHash API, but the array `out` is 32 *bytes*. You're attempting to cast it to a 32 *bit* integer (assuming integers are 32-bit on your platform).